# When should the "self-learning" tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

[self-learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) is described as, "questions about learning English by oneself."
Does it mean I should use it for every question I ask when I am learning English by myself? Or does the tag have a different meaning that it is not completely described in its tag wiki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of these questions seem to be about the subject "self learning."

[self-learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) appears to be a meta tag to label the authors learning technique (i.e. I'm a self learner). If that information is important, it should be included as part of the question text, not a tag. This tag should be removed from those questions.

See [**The Death of Meta Tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).